# Alt key +LMB isn't selecting edge

Tags: modeling, shortcut

I was performing a tutorial for beginners designing a hammer in edit mode. With edge mode selected I attempted to select an edge using alt key + LMB. Nothing happened. However, in prior exercises of same tutorial I was able to select edges using same shortcut keys. I couldn't finish my tutorial because blender crashed. I restarted blender to complete my lesson but I came to a blockade when my alt key + LMB stopped working.

Comment: If you are using blender 2.81 you need to double click instead of Alt. Also the select button is now the right mouse button.

Comment: I am assuming you are talking about Loop Select in edge mode. In my version of 2.81 I also use ALT + LMB to loop select. The problem may be that you are not selecting a loop. Add in the default cube test that you can not loop select those edges, then add in a loop cut and you will be able to select all those edges with ALT + LMB. To help selecting a non-loop, try clicking CTRL+LMB on a few edges as this will try to pick the shortest path.